# Qtip: 1.0 too much recursion

Tags: jquery, qtip

I was given a simple project of displaying images with a mouseover event using jquery. The goal is to display a qtip only if it is mousedover, beforehand it bound all of them on load and it was really slow. They use qtip 1.0 and I run into a 'Too much recursion error' and I'm having trouble identifying where the recursion occurs. I did some research and it may have something to do with event bubbling but haven't been able to fix it yet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".employee" ).hover(function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         var content = '<img src="/upload_test/';
        <!--  content += $(this).attr('id'); -->
          content += 'test.jpg';
          content += '" alt="Loading thumbnail..." height="202" width="254" />';

        $("#" + event.target.id).qtip(
          {
             content: content,
             position: {
                corner: {
                   tooltip: 'leftTop',
                   target: 'leftTop'
                }
             },
             style: {
                 height:202,
                 width:280,
             border: {
                 width: 7,
                 radius: 5,
                 color: 'black'
          }
                 // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection

             },
            hide: { fixed: true, delay: 1000 }
          });
    });

});
```

Comment: Any chance of updating to qtip2?

Comment: I doubt it, they don't upgrade unless the absolutely have to.

Comment: Maybe it makes a new instance every time you hover. You could try destroying it before creating it. `$("#" + event.target.id).qtip('destroy');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Meh, the problem was that I didn't read the manual properly and implemented it incorrectly. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to share with the community the way you resolved your issue. The goal of stackoverflow is to have Q and A. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

why not use **event.currentTarget** instead:

```
 $("#" + event.currentTarget.id).qtip( ...
```

also you can check that the currentTarget is clicking a specific class or id to make sure what you are clicking is the element you want to trigger

```
if($(e.currentTarget).is(".some-class")){

     // code goes here for qtip
     $("#" + event.currentTarget.id).qtip( ...
     ...
}
```

i cant see your markup..but using event delegation like i did above by checking what your clicking is want you want to click so it doesn't bubble up the DOM